Hardware requirement for multi-modal LLMs
I have a request to host a multi-modal LLM to process documents with charts and handwriting. I was thinking about testing Llama 3.2 90B.
What is the hardware requirement for it?
Where can I find some figures about the performance on a server with NVIDIA A100x?

(V)RAM requirement for inference: Model size < RAM requirements < Model size * 1.2.
Also https://huggingface.co/spaces/hf-accelerate/model-memory-usage is helpful, e.g.:

